# a_set = set(a_file) TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
with open('a_file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    a_file = [row for row in reader]
csvfile.close()
with open('b_file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    b_file = [row for row in reader]
csvfile.close()
# create sets
a_set = set(a_file)
b_set = set(b_file)
# find common elements
common = a_set & b_set
# find elements only in a
a_only = a_set.difference(b_set)
# find elements only in b
b_only = b_set.difference(b_set)
```

my code is this for extracting different texts from two csv files and putting them in two different variables.

Comment: *Always* include the full traceback of your error; now we have to guess as to what line is causing this. What input did you give your code? What output did you expect instead?

Comment: You are creating *list of lists*, you cannot put those in sets. Do you have 1 or more than one column in your files? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Sr No. Object Status
  
1 machine passed
2 gantry passed
3 couch failed
4 beam passed

this is my input and i just want the last column values and check whether its passed or failed.

Answer (score 3):

`a_file` is a list of lists, thus it can't be converted into a `set`. The elements of a `set` need to be immutable (so they can be assigned a stable hash value), and `list`s are mutable.

If you did

```
a_file = [tuple(row) for row in reader]
```

(and did the same for `b_file`), then it should work.

Also, no need to close `csvfile`, the `with` block is taking care of that.